# where does web3 created account go in rpc? mainnet or testnet?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

i follow very simple code sample like this:

```
 geth --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal,web3
```

start geth first, then:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3();
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));

var newAccount = web3.personal.newAccount("yo");
console.log(newAccount)
```

but it only gives me address:

```
0x674061cff43583883088aa95e165d638ef5566b3
```

and i dont know if it resides in mainnet or testnet, it also didnt give me private key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to generate an ethereum address + private key, you should use [`web3.eth.accounts.create()`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#create):

```
web3.eth.accounts.create();
> {
    address: "0xb8CE9ab6943e0eCED004cDe8e3bBed6568B2Fa01",
    privateKey: "0x348ce564d427a3311b6536bbcff9390d69395b06ed6c486954e971d960fe8709",
    signTransaction: function(tx){...},
    sign: function(data){...},
    encrypt: function(password){...}
}

web3.eth.accounts.create('2435@#@#@±±±±!!!!678543213456764321§34567543213456785432134567');
> {
    address: "0xF2CD2AA0c7926743B1D4310b2BC984a0a453c3d4",
    privateKey: "0xd7325de5c2c1cf0009fac77d3d04a9c004b038883446b065871bc3e831dcd098",
    signTransaction: function(tx){...},
    sign: function(data){...},
    encrypt: function(password){...}
}

web3.eth.accounts.create(web3.utils.randomHex(32));
> {
    address: "0xe78150FaCD36E8EB00291e251424a0515AA1FF05",
    privateKey: "0xcc505ee6067fba3f6fc2050643379e190e087aeffe5d958ab9f2f3ed3800fa4e",
    signTransaction: function(tx){...},
    sign: function(data){...},
    encrypt: function(password){...}
}
```

My understanding is that this private key + address will be valid on any Ethereum network. Remember that you are not actually "generating" an account. All possible addresses exist on the network at all times, you are simply the first person to use the private key to start having that account sign transactions.

Answer (score 0):

When you created the web3 object using:

`web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));`

You are giving information about the node, including the `chainId`, so the account is valid in the network to which your node is connected.